# Neural Net ConvNetJs - Why can't it converge

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

First ... I don't think this is an issue with ConvNetJs, I think this is an issue with my understanding of neural nets.

Given 2 random numbers, detect if when added together the result is even.

Example:

[4,6] = true

[3,4] = false

My setup:

```
var layer_defs = [];
layer_defs.push({type:'input', out_sx:1, out_sy:1, out_depth:2});
layer_defs.push({type:'fc', num_neurons:20, activation:'relu'});
layer_defs.push({type:'softmax', num_classes:2});

net = new convnetjs.Net();
net.makeLayers(layer_defs);
var trainer = new convnetjs.Trainer(net, {method: 'adadelta', l2_decay: 0.001,batch_size: 10}
```

I then trained it (with random numbers) for 10,000 iterations. It never gets close. About 56% accuracy at best.

Using the same setup but different problem:

Is the first number larger than the second.
It gets with in 99% accuracy in under 1,000 iterations.

Things I have tried:
More layers
More Neurons
svm vs softmax

I'm wondering if this is a "non-classifiable' problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the problem of adding two numbers and classifying the result as odd or even isn't appropriate for a neural network. A neural network attempts to estimate a function. The smoother the function that is being estimated the easier it is for the neural network to converge. (That might not be 100% true but will do for this problem)

To help visualize why these two problems are so different assume for a minute that we make the first number constant. Now consider the graph of the problem where you add a second number and try to determine if the result is odd or even. This graph will oscillate back and forth with each increment of the second number.

The second problem however, will be a much simpler graph. The graph will have only one spot where it switches from less than, to equal, to more than.

Comment: I follow you. Is there an easy way to tell when you are asking a question that is not really a function?

Comment: I like to try to think of the possible graph of the solution. (Not always very easy to imagine.) If the graph is smooth everything goes much better. The two problems you presented are interesting because they demonstrate the extremes. One very un-smooth oscillation, and one smooth simple curve.